# IndexError: index 1040 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1040

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, index-error

I'm trying to understand a code for a project and i am trying to compile it. So i found this problem.

```
cpt=0
for img in t :
    x = img_to_array(img)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    x = preprocess_input(x)
    X_train1[cpt,:,:] = x[0,:,:,:]
    cpt+=1
```

> IndexErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
>        in ()

```
      4     x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
      5     x = preprocess_input(x)
----> 6     X_train1[cpt,:,:] = x[0,:,:,:]
      7     cpt+=1
```

> IndexError: index 1040 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1040

Comment: so what is the *problem*?

Comment: It gives me an error :


    IndexError: index 1040 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1040

Comment: I think @BlueRineS means what is the context. This code gives us literally 0 info of the problem itself. (What is t, for example)

Comment: Repeating yourself does not clarify the problem. We need more info. Why is that error a *problem*? Is it undesired? If so, what output would you expect instead? What did you try yourself to solve it?

Comment: I'm a begginer, i don't have much experience, i dont work with python normaly. I've much more experience with matlab.
I was hoping someone might explain to me the problem.

Comment: @HoussamAJAHA So you are simply trying to understand what `IndexError` means? Ah well, an IndexError turns up when you try to index an array beyond its length. e.g. A list has length (5) but you are trying to retrieve its 10th value..

Comment: Oh okay, but why do i find this error when i've already defined all the variables :

X_train1 = np.zeros(shape=(1040, 224, 224, 3))

Y_train1 = np.zeros(shape=(1040,4))

Y_train1[0:260,0] = 1

Y_train1[260:520,1] = 1

Y_train1[520:780,2] = 1
Y_train1[780:1040,3] = 1

Answer (score 1):

Wherever `X_train1` is created, it is too small as the error suggests: `IndexError: index 1040 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1040`. Python lists as well as `numpy` arrays are 0-based. Therefore, the largest index in an array of size 1040 would be 1039.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the creation of `X_train1`, you have likely created `X_train1` with `t.len() - 1` create it with `t.len()` instead